# How to copy a topic from a kafka cluster to another kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka

One way to do that as the Kafka documentation shows is through *kafka.tools.MirrorMaker* which can do that trick. However, I need to copy a topic (say ***test*** with 1 partition) (its content and meta data) from a production environment to a development environment where connectivity is not there. I could do simple file transfer between environments though.
My question: if I move the ***.log** and **.index** from the folder *test-0* to the destination Kafka cluster, is that good enough? Or there is more that I need to do like meta data and ZooKeeper-related data that I need to move too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copying the log and indexes will not suffice - kafka stores offsets and topic meta data in zookeeper. MirrorMaker is actually a quite simple tool, it spawns consumers to the source topic as well as producers to the target topic and runs until all consumers consumed the source queue. You can't find a simpler process to migrate a topic.

Answer (score 3):

## Use [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/)

### Unless your data is binary,

you can use a stock kafkacat.

**Write topic to file:**

```
kafkacat -b broker:9092 -e -K, -t my-topic > my-topic.txt
```

**Write file back to topic:**

```
kafkacat -b broker:9092 -K, -t my-topic -l my-topic.txt
```

### If your data is binary,

you unfortunately have to build your own kafkacat from [this branch](https://github.com/fryckbos/kafkacat/tree/base64), which is an as of yet unmerged PR.

**Write topic with binary values to file:**

```
kafkacat -b broker:9092 -e -Svalue=base64 -K, -t my-topic > my-topic.txt
```

**Write file back to topic:**

```
kafkacat -b broker:9092 -Svalue=base64 -K, -t my-topic -l my-topic.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in your scenario was the following sequence of actions:

1. Create the topic in Kafka where you will later insert your files (with 1 partition and 1 replica and an appropriate `retention.ms` config so that Kafka doesn't delete your presumably outdated segments).
2. Stop your Kafka and Zookeeper.
3. Find the location of the files of the 0-partition you created in Kafka in step 1 (it will be something like `kafka-logs-<hash>/<your-topic>-0`).
4. In this folder, remove the existing files and copy your files to it.
5. Start Kafka and Zookeeper.

This also works if your Kafka is run from docker-compose (but you'll have to set up an appropriate volume, of course).