# How to take a dump of data from hosted kafka cluster and import the data into local kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes

I have a Kafka cluster in [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) with a lot of test data. I want to have some/all of that test data imported into my local Kafka cluster. This, way it would be easier for me to perform tests in the local environment with actual data from kubernetes.

So, is there a way to dump for eg: *5000 messages from a kafka topic* into a file and restore them into a local kafka topic ?

Comment: Check out MirrorMaker? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549639/how-to-copy-a-topic-from-a-kafka-cluster-to-another-kafka-cluster?rq=1

Comment: Also consider `kubectl cp`, which will let  you copy kafka and zookeeper data dirs to your local directory. Not sure if this will work well with data that hasn't been fsynced, etc

Comment: Also consider kafka-rest-proxy? Not quite a data dump, but gets you access to your data

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky I checked MirrorMaker. It seems to be helpful when I have to replicate a topic entirely to another cluster. But I didn't find any option to migrate only a part or certain number of topic data. This is because I may not need all the cloud topic data in my local machine.

Comment: Yeah it’s not exactly it. I’ve been looking for an answer to this question as well. Please post if you find out.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Replicator](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-replicator/docs/index.html) is a commercial tool that enables you to replicate topics from one cluster to another. Similar to MirrorMaker though, it's designed to replicate *entire* topics, not just part of them.
2. You can use [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat) with `stdin`/`stdout` if you just want some kind of hacky option, but things like partitioning, topic config and all that stuff that you'd want to match for accurate testing you would have to ensure gets done properly.

Answer (score 2):

The way we do it (not on Kubernetes but it does not matter in this case) is:

1. if we need to duplicate some part of data from our production cluster to a local/test cluster - we start a Flume agent that reads from prod Kafka cluster and pushes into test cluster. This only works with either live data (when you start your copy process now and let it run for whatever time is needed, capturing the live traffic), or if it is Ok to start getting data from the EARLIEST offset - because vanilla Flume per se does not allow you to specify specific range of offsets to consume from a topic (AFAIK)
2. if we do need data from a very specific range of offsets - we just run a very simple Java client (our own custom one, just a few lines of code) that seeks to the beginning offset and reads until the specified end offset of the source cluster/topic - and sends the events into the target Kafka cluster/topic

we found these approaches simpler and more flexible that using more complex tools/frameworks like MirrorMaker.

Comment: Why would you say the flume agent is simpler than mirromaker. Also, I don’t know anything about flume: does it preserve record metadata like timestamps?

Comment: Yea, "simpler" is a subjective term :)  Based on our and others' research (like this from Uber - https://eng.uber.com/ureplicator/ - although , granted, it is based on an older version), it looked like you had to be very careful in setting up MirrorMaker for a zero-data-loss transfer, especially in the case of periodic unavailability/network issues with a target cluster. Doable, of course - but with a non-negligible effort. We already had Flume used for data collection, so setting up one more agent with a durable channel and disk spillover was "easy" :) . Just one more option.

Comment: Oh, and yes, event metadata (like timestamps) is in headers , and by default Flume preserves all headers, although you also can modify them if needed.

Comment: Thank you. My main use case at the moment is just getting my production data to my local computer. It's not so easy! I will check out flume.